# Laravel Queue fall asleep when Queue is empty

Tags: laravel, performance, queue, jobs

I have a controller function which dispatchs a `job`. When this `job` is handled, at the end it dispatch the same `job` again (with different args). There are 5 jobs of the same in total.

`Queue driver: database`

The problem is: I record the time duration from `create()` to `handle()`. The first job dispatched by the controller took 1700ms, where the other jobs dispatched by the jobs themselves took only 40ms.

`Queue driver: sync`

When I changed to use `sync` queue driver, all the jobs worked in lightning speed.

**Findings:**

The first queue job took long time from `create()` to `handle()`. Before that the queue was empty. It might be the queue driver problem.

Why and how to fix please? thanks!!

**UPDATE:**

Added a `TestJob` that dispatch itself when job was handled. That meant the queue always had a `TestJob` being handled or waiting for handling.

Repeating my original jobs, they all took only <70ms from `created()` to `handle()` completed.

**Conclusion:**

I am pretty sure it is the queue driver problem. Looks like the worker fall asleep when the queue is empty. Do anyone know the fix please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I post my answer here, hope to be useful to someone else on the internet.

**Reference**

https://divinglaravel.com/queue-system/workers

**Answer**

After putting `echo` and `echo debug_backtrace()[1]['function'];` everywhere, it was found that there was DEFAULT VALUE of sleep when queue was empty, inside `Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand`

> protected $signature = 'queue:work{--sleep=3 : Number of seconds to sleep when no job is available}

**Solution**

so the solution is to mention `sleep` in the console command:

```
php artisan queue:work --sleep=0
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sleep can be [a float](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L758). Reducing sleep time may increase CPU usage.